# problems routing WAN with private IPs and LAN with public IPs

Tags: routing, firewall, pfsense

I have just installed pfsense 2.4 for a SOHO I work and I'm getting problems with the routing.
I have asked my ISP for a /29 network with public ips for the DMZ, but instead of giving my directly what I asked they gave me a this:

WAN 10.219.16.244/30

LAN 152.206.43.32/29

(these are not the real ips the gave me)

So, I have something like this:

[image]

the connection between my pfsense and the isp gateway works just fine but there is no way i get internet connection.
What I'm missing here?

(I've done this before but with a public IP on the WAN side)

Hope you could help me!
Thanks anyway

Comment: Are you sure they didn't just typo, say LAN on that line when they meant WAN? Have you tried it in reverse, is what I'm asking.

Comment: no, i am pretty sure that is what they meant. In fact, i called my isp and asked them about it and they reassured it was correct.

Comment: First, we really need to see the router configuration. Please copy it and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). It sounds like you are using a residential ISP that is using CGNAT, and that is going to prevent access from the public Internet if you have a double NAT.

Comment: @RonMaupin Maybe but I've not ever seen a residential account that the ISP allowed to have a /29, since that implies you're operating a business which they frown upon (from my experience) and require you to upgrade to a business-class connection to be able to get a anything other than a single IP address.

Comment: @JesseP. I have, in the past, leased a block of IPv4 addresses from a residential ISP. They simply charge more for that, and it ends up costing a lot more than a standard residential account, but without the protections of a business contract.

Comment: @RonMaupin Interesting. What ISP was that?

Comment: There were several. At one time, I think Covad, there was another that was local to the Dallas area, and I cannot remember the name of that one, even though I had it for years. The problem with those is that the government (state?) ended up letting the incumbent telcos charge them out of business for leasing of residential lines. They ended up needing to charge customers triple what the crappy incumbent telco or cable vendors charge. We had a competitive market: the incumbents were required to give wholesale pricing to competition, not charge _more_ than a customer of the telco would pay.

Comment: @JesseP., leasing IP addresses on a residential line led to some confusion with one of the ISPs (SWB?). When I called the residential help, they said I must call the business help, and the business help would see that I had a residential line, so they referred me back to residential help, but the residential help wasn't up to the task, and I always ended up with the business help to resolve any problem. I  didn't have that problem with them in Austin, but Dallas was different, even though it was the same ISP. It didn't last long for me in Dallas.

Comment: @RonMaupin Wow. That's crazy. The sad part is that with net neutrality repealed currently (sort of) there's probably a lot of price gouging right now, like that.

Comment: @RonMaupin Gotta love the "it's someone else's problem, let me transfer you" game.  They don't listen to you telling them NOT to transfer you - they get paid by the completed call most of the time, so getting you off their phone is their highest priority.

Comment: @JesseP., yes, the FCC says that they are backing off and have no control over Internet providers, and that competition is working well to keep everyting in line.

Comment: i live in cuba. my isp is the only one available ETECSA. it is not a residential line, it is for the company i work for

Comment: *... there is no way i get internet connection*: did you assign an address from the /29 to the inside of the pfSense and tested with PING using that address as source address? Your pfSense should not do any NAT by the way.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're just sending the route for your public block to their equipment, which then routes it to your pfSense via the /30 access segment (no NAT being done - just handing off the connection between interfaces on the ISP equipment), which they then expect you to NAT or forward on to another device behind the pfSense (to do the NAT there), like just using the pfSense as a router without translation, and having another device to perform the NAT later in the path.

Basically, on your pfSense, you need to set its default route to be the ISPs side of the /30 segment. Then, set an interface on the pfSense with the first host IP address on the /29 (to be your gateway for the other hosts), then on your DMZ (whatever that is), you would assign your other IP addresses and set the gateway to be your pfSense.

Comment: i beleive you are on the right  track.

Comment: i believe you are on the right  track and i have done mostly as you said. my pfsense default gateway is the first available ip of the /30 wan network, the other ip is in my pfsense wan interface. in fact i can do ping to the gateway in the isp. so far so good. in the lan side of my pfsense i got the first ip of the /29 (those that are public ips). i disabled nat rules created by pfsense by default since i dont believe i have to nat (why should i nat public ips to privates ips to get to the internet?)  do you agree with me?

Comment: @JorgeRegalado You don't have to use NAT if you don't want to - your servers can have public IP addresses directly - but adding NAT allows you have more hosts than what would be allowed if you assign the public IP addresses to your servers directly. You could have hundreds of servers behind a single public IP address if you add NAT into the mix. It's ultimately your call - I can't answer that for you. Additionally, NAT adds a layer of obscurity to hide your server's real addresses and your internal subnet architecture.

Comment: I understand what you say. What i really meant Is that apparently the problem should not be that i am not doing nat from my lan to wan.  If so, what else could ir be?

Comment: @JorgeRegalado Did you assign something in your DMZ one of the other /29 addresses, with the pfSense set as the default gateway for the DMZ server, and see if you can reach the internet?

Comment: no i haven't. I assumed that if the pfsense can't access the internet, no other server using one of the other /29 IP address with the pfsense as Gateway can't do either..

Comment: I'll try tomorrow and Let you know. Appreciate your help

Comment: @JorgeRegalado If your pfSense is set with a proper default route (that points to the ISP device on the other end of the /30 subnet as the gateway), and you're sourcing the traffic from the interface with the public IP address they assigned to you, it should work.

Comment: @JorgeRegalado Any luck?

Comment: @JorgeRegalado Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 1):

> there is no way i get internet connection.

What makes you say that? While it is highly discouraged for non-NAT'd interfaces to have private addresses, it happens all over the place. No, the internet cannot talk to the WAN interfaces when they don't have global addresses, but that has nothing to do with how they route traffic. When a packet with src:152.206.43.33-dst:8.8.8.8 arrives on either side of the WAN, the router will route them as-is. The rest of the internet will not know that packet crossed a private addressed link, or a link with no address at all.

You will need to take steps to prevent pfsense from trying to use it's private WAN address to talk to things on the internet. (obviously)

(If the router (pfsense) needs to send an ICMP error, the RFC1918 address could be a problem, which is why use of non-nat'd private addresses is not recommended. On some systems it's possible to configure which interface is used for ICMP errors.)

(See Also: Cisco's `ip unnumbered`)